# Find out which is latest between two commit strings

Tags: git, git-log

Let's say I have the two commit IDs: `ba8a919` and `c15a66b`, how do I know which one is the latest?

Comment: How do you define latest?

Comment: latest in terms of commit date

Answer (score 4):

Use `git log` to get commit date. The `-1` limits output to one row

```
git log -1 --pretty="%h %cd" ba8a919 
git log -1 --pretty="%h %cd" c15a66b
```

You could do something fancy..

```
ONE=ba8a919
TWO=c15a66b
if [[ `git log $ONE..$TWO` == "" ]]; then
  echo $TWO is newer
else
  echo $ONE is newer
fi
```

Comment: Note that "newer by ancestry" and "newer by date" can produce different answers. The two commits may not have an ancestor/descendant relationship (perhaps both have the same parent but are just siblings of each other). So the "right" method really depends on context.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of simplicity,

```
git log -1 ba8a919 c15a66b
```

works too, since you're asking for both but limiting output to one.

It works both ways, of course, you could feed

```
git log -1 c15a66b ba8a919
```

and have the same output, the latest of both.

---

Script version : in case you needed to have that in a script, taking two hashes as parameters and expecting a hash in return, go for the plumbing counterpart :

```
git rev-list -1 <hash1> <hash2>
# returns the long-form hash of the latest one
```

Comment: The sorting is by committer date by default. You can change this to author date with `--author-date-order`. Note that `--since` and `--until` (or `--before` and `--after`) always work with the committer date, regardless of sort order.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, I've edited. Much clearer now!